# Problem uploading file using python and Urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

```
import os
import sys
import time
import base64
import hmac
import mimetypes
import urllib2
from hashlib import sha1
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

def read_data(file_object):
    while True:
        r = file_object.read(1 * 1024)
        print 'rrr',r
        if not r:
            print 'r'
            file_object.close()
            break
        yield r

def upload_file(filename, bucket):
    print 'start'
    length = os.stat(filename).st_size
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    date = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT", time.gmtime())

print 'before'
register_openers()
print 'after'
input_file = open(filename, 'r')
print 'read mode'
data = read_data(input_file)
request = urllib2.Request(bucket, data=data)

request.add_header('Date', date)
request.add_header('Content-Type', content_type)
request.add_header('Content-Length', length)

request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
print 'before lamda'
urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

upload_file('C:\\test.pdf', "http://10.105.158.132:26938/DocLib1/ste.pdf")
```

the above code is for streaming and uploading the data. streaming is performing fine. While uploading, code hangs in following code 
**urllib2.urlopen(request).read()**

Comment: the address http://10.105.158.132:26938/DocLib1/ste.pdf produces a connection timed out in my navigator. Is it correct?

Comment: it appears that your indentation is incorrect. Lines between `print  'before'` and `urllib2.urlopen` should be indented (to be inside `upload_file()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One showstopper may be your arguments populating the urllib2.Request

```
request = urllib2.Request(bucket, data=data)
```

The first argument should be a valid URL.  From your shared code it doesn't appeared bucket has been populated with the URL to S3 for wherever.  That would cause urlopen to fail as it is using the returned value for that call.

Answer (score 0):

Use **strace** or a network sniffer like **Wireshark** for hunting the problem down.